# Unable to install Apache Cassandra 4.0.5 on Red Hat 7 / CentOS 7

Tags: cassandra, centos7, redhat

I'm trying to install Apache Cassandra on **Red Hat 7** via `yum` as described here https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html. The installation process was successful with version 4.0.3.

However, with the latest version 4.0.5 the following error message is returned during the installation process `Error: Invalid version flag: or`.
The `or` operator was added to the Apache Cassandra configuration with https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/cd0a40d09e5c029e3cac260ecf4cb3dc02deabc7.

From my understanding the `or` operator was introduced with the RPM version 4.13 but Red Hat 7 ships with 4.11.3.

Is there any other solution than upgrading to a new Red Hat version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.

I found this jira ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-17765

On centos 7, it should be fixed by cassandra version 4.0.6, 4.1-beta, 4.1

Comment: Please edit and clarify your answer. Answer should provide some context. Not only the link. You can add some examples or quote from link and add link as source and for further exploring.

Answer (score 1):

This is still happening on Cassandra `4.1.0`. I successfully installed it on *Centos 7* after I changed the repo `baseUrl` to *noboolean* path (basically, you just need to append `/noboolean` string to the path and that's it). Steps to fix the issue:

1. Run the `vi /etc/yum.repos.d/cassandra.repo` command
2. Set `baseurl=https://redhat.cassandra.apache.org/41x/noboolean` and save the file
3. Run the `sudo yum install cassandra` (as stated in the [official docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html#installing-the-rpm-packages))

Works fine. Cassandra 4.1 is up and running in the cluster. Centos 8+ doesn't need this change and official instructions work well as they are.